# :first-child and :last-child not working in owl carousel 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, owl-carousel

I am using Owl carousel 2 and have added custom CSS:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
    navigation: true,
    pagination: true,
    lazyLoad: true
  });
});
```

```css
#owl-demo .owl-item > div img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}
#owl-demo .owl-item > div {
  padding: 0px 2px
}
#owl-demo .owl-item > div:first-child {
  border: 6px solid #e1e1e1;
}
```

```html
<div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel">
  <div>
    <img class='lazyOwl' data-src="http://placehold.it/200x200/42bdc2/FFFFFF&text=1st Row" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img class='lazyOwl' data-src="http://placehold.it/200x200/42bdc2/FFFFFF&text=1st Row" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img class='lazyOwl' data-src="http://placehold.it/200x200/42bdc2/FFFFFF&text=1st Row" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/owl-carousel/owl.theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

This worked for me but I would like to use `:last-child` OR `:first-child` to add a CSS border to only first or last `div`. In action this does not work and instead shows a border for all `div`s.

How can I fix this?

DEMO [here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/8bJUc/814/)

Comment: While I have a pretty good idea what you are expecting and how to fix it please could you clarify how exactly this is not working and the result you are after to stop potential answers not addressing the issue you are facing.

Comment: @HiddenHobbes: true, i edit my Q

Comment: can you check this [demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/8bJUc/815/) is this what is expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is slightly wrong when using `:first-child`. Targeting the `div` inside `.owl-item` with `:first-child` will result in all the `div`s being selected as they are the first `div` within `.owl-item`.

What you need to do is use `:first-child` to find the first instance of `.owl-item` then target the `div` inside that.

The following changes are required:

- Change `#owl-demo .owl-item > div:first-child` to `#owl-demo .owl-item:first-child div`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
    navigation: true,
    pagination: true,
    lazyLoad: true
  });
});
```

```css
#owl-demo .owl-item > div img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}
#owl-demo .owl-item > div {
  padding: 0px 2px
}
#owl-demo .owl-item:first-child div {
  border: 6px solid #e1e1e1;
}
```

```html
<div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel">
  <div>
    <img class='lazyOwl' data-src="http://placehold.it/200x200/42bdc2/FFFFFF&text=1st Row" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img class='lazyOwl' data-src="http://placehold.it/200x200/42bdc2/FFFFFF&text=1st Row" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img class='lazyOwl' data-src="http://placehold.it/200x200/42bdc2/FFFFFF&text=1st Row" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/owl-carousel/owl.theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/wkh1mx2e/

Comment: This worked But if I add More `div` with `class` not work see demo: http://fiddle.jshell.net/wkh1mx2e/1/

Comment: @NewCod3r This will work with classes too, you just need to ensure you apply `:first-child` to `.owl-item`. So `#owl-demo .owl-item .info:first-child` should be `#owl-demo .owl-item:first-child .info`. You need to find the first child of `.owl-wrapper` which is the `.owl-item` `div` then apply the style to the `.info` `div` inside. http://fiddle.jshell.net/2s4LLoeo/